# iOS Images not caching correctly

Tags: ios, caching, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm having trouble caching and displaying the cached images.
It's a collection view with a lot of images.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *imageMP = [_imageCache objectForKey:[self getImage:indexPath.row]];

    NSLog(@"looking for \"%@\"",[self getImage:indexPath.row]);

    if (imageMP) {
         NSLog(@"found it!");
        cell.img_pic.image = imageMP;

    }else{
        //display loading pic so long
        cell.img_pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];

        [self.queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            UIImage *image = [self getActualImage:indexPath.row];
            if (image) {
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    cell.img_pic.image = image;
                }];
                [_imageCache setObject:image forKey:[self getImage:indexPath.row]];

                NSLog(@"saving as \"%@\"",[self getImage:indexPath.row]);
            }
        }];

    }
```

It loads and displays the images correctly, the problem is with saving to cache and then displaying from cache.

The outputs of the NSLog to the console is as follows

```
looking for "/var/mobile/Applications/CAF51B4B-6FAF-4775-A201-EF670BB50462/Documents/7_MP.jpeg"
saving as   "/var/mobile/Applications/CAF51B4B-6FAF-4775-A201-EF670BB50462/Documents/7_MP.jpeg"
looking for "/var/mobile/Applications/CAF51B4B-6FAF-4775-A201-EF670BB50462/Documents/7_MP.jpeg"
saving as   "/var/mobile/Applications/CAF51B4B-6FAF-4775-A201-EF670BB50462/Documents/7_MP.jpeg"
looking for "/var/mobile/Applications/CAF51B4B-6FAF-4775-A201-EF670BB50462/Documents/7_MP.jpeg"
saving as   "/var/mobile/Applications/CAF51B4B-6FAF-4775-A201-EF670BB50462/Documents/7_MP.jpeg"
```

It never correctly displays the cached image,otherwise it would print "found it!"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem.

```
_imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
```

I just forgot to alloc and init the NSCache.

Answer (score 1):

use JMCache (https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache) and then use the following code

```
 [cell.img_pic.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"laoding.png"]];
```